# ¿Como ver todos los detalles de un solo registro en una ventana Modal?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Es un crud realizado con boostrap que te permite ver al detalle a cada cliente, tiene 16 columnas en total, pero en la tabla solo se ve lo necesario, quiero que al presionar el voton VER se pueda visualizar las demas columnas en una tabla que esta en un modal, he intenda pero no tengo idea como hacerlo :c, aqui dejo el codigo

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#insertar">
  Nuevo Registro
  </button> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-id">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">F. Ingreso</th>
          <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
          <th scope="col">Celular</th>
          <th scope="col">DNI</th>
          <th scope="col">Equipo</th>
          <th scope="col">Diagnostico</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $usuarios);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["ID"] ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row["F_Ingreso"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["Cliente"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["Celular"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["DNI"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["Equipo"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["Diagnostico"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["F_Salida"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Marca"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Serie"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Accesorios"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["F_Compra"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Detalle_Problema"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Procedimiento"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["Resultado"] ?></td>
          <td style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"><?php echo $row["T_Responsable"] ?></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#mostrar">Ver</a></td>      
  <td><a class="btn btn-danger " href="#" data-href="delete.php? id=<?php echo $row["ID"]  ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminar">Eliminar</a></td>
  <td><a class="btn btn-success editbtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editar">Editar</a></td>

          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Esta es la ventada Modal que estaba intentando hacer, abre pero no se como mostrar los datos, con el boton editar te muestra el formulario de registro con los datos listos a editar sin problema, he intentado con input como en EDITAR pero todo se agrupo y no se puede visualizar correctamente

```
div class="modal-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-id" method="post">
      <thead>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th scope="col">Fecha de Ingreso</th>
       <th scope="row">Cliente</th>
       <th scope="col">Celular</th>
       <th scope="col">DNI</th>
       <th scope="col">Equipo</th>
       <th scope="col">Marca</th>
       <th scope="col">Serie</th>
       <th scope="col">Accesorio</th>
       <th scope="col">Fecha de Compra</th>
       <th scope="col">Problema</th>
       <th scope="col">Diagnostico</th>
       <th scope="col">Procedimiento</th>
       <th scope="col">Resultado</th>
       <th scope="col">Tecnico Responsalbe</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="align-bottom">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abriendo el modal con un evento onclick de javascript
llamas un archivo.php externo donde se vean todos los datos de un ID.

- Debes incluir jquery o local o por cdn, si no lo tenés en la pagina

BOTON EN TU TABLA

```
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalmostrar" onclick="mostrar(<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Ver</a></td>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    function mostrar(id) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mostrar_resul").load("archivo.php?id=" + id, " ", function () {
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

MODAL

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalmostrar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-sm-16">
                        <div class="widget-box">
                          <div class="widget-header">
                            <h5 class="widget-title">Mostrar todos los datos</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button></div>
                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <div class="panel-body" id="mostrar_resul" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-footer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

archivo.php

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
/* aqui haces la consulta y mostrar los datos por el ID */
?>
```